# reduce(prev , curr) function return undefined in react redux

Tags: reactjs, filter, redux, include, reduce

brands = ["nike", "caprese", "lifestyle", "puma"]

products = {name: "fullname", tags: ["caprese", "lifestyle"]}

```
return products.filter(product => {
   return brand.reduce((prev , curr) => {
       if (tags.includes(curr) > -1) {
            return prev && true;
        }
   },true);
})
```

I want to filter products with brands but it returns undefined, the first time it's working but once I change product tags then it returns undefined

Comment: products is an object, you can't use `filter` on an object as it expects a collection.

Comment: yeah, i know and i have products collection

Comment: products =[ {name: "fullname", tags: ["caprese", "lifestyle"]}, name: "fullname", tags: ["caprese", "lifestyle"]},name: "fullname", tags: ["caprese", "lifestyle"]}]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
return products.filter(({ tags }) => tags.some(tag => brands.includes(tag));
```

the `some` function returns true if the condition holds for at least one element.

Comment: actualy i have multiple filters here

export const getVisibleproducts = (data, { brand, value, sortBy, startPrice, endPrice }) => {
    return data.products.filter(product => {
        return brand.reduce((prev , curr) => {
            if (product.tags.includes(curr) > -1) {
                return prev && true;
            }
        }, true);
        const startPriceMatch = typeof value.min !== 'number' || value.min <= product.price;
        const endPriceMatch = typeof value.max !== 'number' || product.price <= value.max;
        return  startPriceMatch && endPriceMatch;
    })
}

Comment: okay, i mean i have multiple filters there. so i want return true, so that item only show frontend.

Comment: Thank You Very Much , it's Working Great.